# regular expression for route parameter of URL

Tags: php, regex, kohana

I'm not great with regular expressions, thats why I need your help.
look here http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing#examples:

```
Route::set('search', ':<query>', array('query' => '.*'))
  ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'Search',
    'action' => 'index',
  ));
```

this regular expression (`.*`) excepts all parameters what I need:
"`cat1/cat2/cat3`"
but also:
"`cat1/cat 2/       cat3`",
"`cat1/cat 2/ /// a |<>"?\':*`"
How to modify this expression to disallow:
1. any kind of spaces ( "`\s`" )
2. more then one slash together ( '`cat1/cat2`' but not '`cat1/////cat2`')
3. and each symbol of range : [ `"|", "<", ">" , "\"", "?", "\", "'", ":", "*"` ]
Thanks for everyone who try to help me

```
define('CATEGORIES_RGXP', '(?:[^|<>\\?"\':*\s]+\/?)+');
Route::set('debug_route', '(<categories>/)<file>.<ext>',array(
    'categories'    => CATEGORIES_RGXP,
))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller'        =>  'index',
        'action'            =>  'file',
    ));
```

Dump in controller when i follow "/cat1/cat2/////cat3/file.php": `var_dump($this->request->param());`

```
array(3) {
  ["categories"]=>
  string(14) "cat1/cat2/cat3"
  ["file"]=>
  string(4) "file"
  ["ext"]=>
  string(3) "php"
}
```

so it allow to pass a group of few slashes

Comment: Why don't you express this in your route, eg by sth like `:<cat1>/<cat2>/<cat3>`?

Comment: To be possible to use unlimited count of nested categories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `.` matches every character (except new line) which explains the observed behaviour

Instead, we'll use the negated character class ie `[^X]` which means "match everything **but** X"

According to your requirements, you should use then:

```
^((?:[^|<>\\\/?"':*\s]+\/?)+)$
```

#### [`DEMO`](https://regex101.com/r/kJ3rL3/5)

```
  NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^|<>\\\/?"':*\s         any character except: '|', '<', '>',
      ]+                       '\\', '\/', '?', '"', ''', ':', '*',
                               whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (1 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: I think you have great knowledges in using of regular expression but: from "cat1/cat2/cat3" it selects only "cat3" and don't want to work with static method "set" of "Route" class

Comment: @LINKeRxUA simply put the whole pattern inside parenthesis to capture the matches... Check my edited answer